# Is there a way to convert my Angular ASP.net Core template to ASP.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to build a web api for my Angular project and I'm choosing ASP.net. I have used the Angular Asp.net core template and I'm almost finished with the Angular front end. I want to know if I need to convert the template to MVC? if yes is it possible to convert it or do I need to start from scratch? If I start the backend from the scratch is there a way to unplug the Angular Front end?

Comment: You can just use .Net Core2.2 instead of 3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you make a new MVC project (make sure to include WebApi etc for your backend) you can then copy:

```
src //Directory
angular.json
browserslist
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.*
```

They should be put at the root level of the MVC project and should look something like the image

[image: How it should look]

Edit **_layout.chtml** with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
</body>
</html>
```

And create the **bundleconfig.cs** to serve your files:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
            "~/Scripts/lib/runtime*",
            "~/Scripts/lib/polyfills*",
            "~/Scripts/lib/styles*",
            "~/Scripts/lib/scripts*",
            "~/Scripts/lib/vendor*",
            "~/Scripts/lib/main*"));
    }
}
```

Finally update Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Angular App";
}
<app-root></app-root>
```

You'll also want to enable hash urls in your angular app if you havent already (app-routing.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can I also add the node modules?

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\...\source\repos\...\...\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtm

I have done the following steps and I am getting this error for the _layout.cshtml

Do you know of a solution to this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: I'll update my answer when I'm back on my laptop but you need to update where the output goes to by default it goes to dust and needs to be changed to Scripts/lib. Should be found in your angular.json file

Comment: You can either move node_modules or just out npm install and they will be pulled again